# What is the best way to persist login data between multiple web services?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing an application that consumes several web services. There is not a authentication system in place per say however each web service requires a login/password.

So in my application when a user first opens the app, a login/password box prompts them to enter that information. Once entered, that same login/password needs to **persist** for all the other web service calls. What is the best/logical way to persist this information during the session?

your thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) would be a good place to start.

I would also recommend not storing credentials per se, but instead storing the tokens that the web services send back if they support it.

An example are Facebook's APIs. You can have a user login, but you only need to store two pieces of information, an access token and expiration date in order to continue making calls to the API "as" that user.